# Line by line editing to all the files in a folder ( and subfolders ) in perl

Tags: perl, replace

I want my perl program to do the substitution of '{' - > '{function('.counter++.')' in all the files except the lines when there is a '{' and a '}' in the same line, and except when the '{' appears one line under a 'typedef' substring.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "C:/test dir";   


# fill up our argument list with file names:
find(sub { if (-f && /\.[hc]$/) { push @ARGV, $File::Find::name } }, $dir);

$^I = ".bak";   # supply backup string to enable in-place edit 

my $counter = 0; 

# now process our files 
while (<>) 
{
    my @lines;
    # copy each line from the text file to the string @lines and add a function call after every '{' '
    tie @lines, 'Tie::File', $ARGV or die "Can't read file: $!\n"

    foreach  (@lines) 
    {   
        if   (!( index (@lines,'}')!= -1 )) # if there is a '}' in the same line don't add the     macro
            {
                s/{/'{function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge;
                print;
            }

    }
    untie @lines; # free @lines
}
```

what I was trying to do is to go through all the files in @ARGV that i found in my dir and subdirs and             for each *.c or *.h file I want to go line by line and check if this line contains '{'. if it does the program won't check if there is a '{' and won't make the substitution, if it doesn't the program will substitute '{' with '{function('.counter++.');'

unfortunately this code does not work. I'm ashamed to say that I'm trying to make it work all day and still no go.I think that my problem is that I'm not really working with lines where I search for '{' but I don't understand why. I would really appreciate some help.

I would also like to add that I am working in windows environment.

Thank You!!

Edit: so far with your help this is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "C:/projects/SW/fw/phy";   # use forward slashes in paths

# fill up our argument list with file names:
find(sub { if (-f && /\.[hc]$/) { push @ARGV, $File::Find::name } }, $dir);

$^I = ".bak";   # supply backup string to enable in-place edit 

my $counter = 0; 

# now process our files
while (<>) {
    s/{/'{ function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge unless /}/;
    print;
}
```

The only thing that is left to do is to make it ignore '{' substitution when it is one line under 'typedef' substring like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
}examp;
```

I would greatly appreciate your help! Thank you! :)

Edit #2: This is the final code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "C:/exmp";   

# fill up our argument list with file names:
find(sub { if (-f && /\.[hc]$/) { push @ARGV, $File::Find::name } }, $dir);

$^I = ".bak";   # supply backup string to enable in-place edit 

my $counter = 0; 
my $td = 0;

# now process our files
while (<>) {
    s/{/'{ function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge if /{[^}]*$/ && $td == 0;
    $td = do { (/typedef/ ? 1 : 0 ) || ( (/=/ ? 1 : 0 ) && (/if/ ? 0 : 1 ) && (/while/ ? 0 : 1 ) &&             (/for/ ? 0 : 1 ) && (/switch/ ? 0 : 1 ) )}; 
    print;
}
```

The code does the substitution except when the line above the substitution place included 'typedef',
When the line above it included '=' and no 'if', 'while', 'for' or 'switch' the substitiution will also not happen.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Why not sed? `sed -e '/{[^}]*$/{s/{/{function('\''.counter++.'\'');/}' -i.bak *`

Comment: @squiguy Nobody's perfect! ;-)  At all, U could do same using perl... See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i` swith let you presise an extension for *backup files*.

Using perl:

```
perl -pe "/{[^}]*\$/&&do{s/{/{function('.counter++.');/}" -i.bak *
```

or (same result):

```
perl -pe "s/{/{function('.counter++.');/ if /{[^}]*\$/" -i.bak *
```

And for processing all files in sub-folder too, this could be simplier to use `find`:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 perl -pe "s/{/{function('.counter++.');/ if /{[^}]*\$/" -i.bak
```

Using `GNU sed` let you do the job very quickly

```
sed -e "/{[^}]*\$/{s/{/{function('.counter++.');/}" -i.bak *
```

**Edit** For doing modification *only if previous line **don't** contain word `typedef`*:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN { my \$td=1; };s/{/{function('.counter++.');/ if /{[^}]*\$/ && \$td==1 ; \$td=do{/typedef/?0:1};"  -i.bak *
```

could be written;

```
perl -pe "
BEGIN { my \$td=0; };
s/{/{function('.counter++.');/ if /{[^}]*\$/ && \$td==0 ;
\$td=do{/typedef/?1:0};"  -i.bak *
```

or more readable as

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN { my $td=0; };
    s/{/{function(\047.counter++.\047);/ if /{[^}]*$/ && $td==0;
    $td=do{/typedef/?1:0};
  ' -i.bak *
```

Or as a perl script file: `cat >addFunction.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi.bak
BEGIN { my $td = 0; }
s/{/{function(\047.counter++.\047);/ if /{[^}]*$/ && $td == 0;
$td = do { /typedef/ ? 1 : 0 };
```

Explained:

- `BEGIN{...}` command block to do at begin of program.
- `s/// if // &&` to replacement **if** current match match **and** $td=0
- `$td=do{ aaa ? bbb : ccc }` assing to td: if aaa then bbb else ccc.

As perl run sequetialy, `$td` keep his value until next assignement. So if test for replacement is doing before `$td` assignement, the check will use *previous* value.

And finaly, same using sed:

```
sed -e '/{[^}]*$/{x;/./{x;s/{/{function(\o047.counter++.\o047);/;x;};x;};h;s/^.*typedef.*$//;x;' -i.bak *
```

or more readable:

```
sed -e '
    /{[^}]*$/{
        x;
        /./{
            x;
            s/{/{function(\o047.counter++.\o047);/;
            x;
        };
        x;
    };
    h;
    s/^/./;
    s/^.*typedef.*$//;
    x;
' -i.bak *
```

Some `sed` tricks:

- `h` store (backup) current line to *the hold space*
- `x` exchange current working line with *the hold space*
- `s///` well known replacement string command
- `\o047` octal tick: `'`
- `/{[^}]*$/{ ... }` Command block to do only on lines maching `{` and no `}`.
- `/./{ ... }` Command block to do only on lines containing at least 1 character

Comment: Thank you but I also need to add another exception to the substitution which is if the '{' is under a line that has the substring 'typedef' in it. In this case I need to use line by line editing don't I?

Comment: no, perl (like sed) work sequentialy, so you could store previous condition... Please edit your question!

Comment: I edited the question. thanks. do you have a solution to my problem?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think I'm probably doing something wrong. the line that you suggested as the whole code. where do I write it? it gives me a bunch of errors if I try to run it.

Comment: still doesn't work. I guess that it has to do with that I am using windows environment...

Comment: I figured out what my problem was and now it's almost working.
I used your 7th code example and I need to make it increase the counter on every substitution. for the first substitution it will be '{function (0);' for the second it will be '{function(1);' and so on. Can you help me with that.

Thank you and sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: OK I tweaked the code a little bit and made it work! thanks!!

Comment: `BEGIN { my ($td,$cnt)=(0,0); };s/{/"{function(".$cnt++.");"/e if /{[^}]*$/ && $td==0 ; $td=do{/typedef/?1:0};`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to skip the substitution if '}' exists:

```
if ( $_ !~ /}/ ) {  # same as !( $_ =~ /}/ )

    s/{/'{function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge;
}
```

Make sure that the `print` is outside the conditional though, or the line won't be printed if the '}' is missing.

Other ways to write it:

```
unless ( /}/ ) {

    s/{/'{function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge;
}
```

Or simply:

```
s/{/'{function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge unless /}/;
```

Comment: Wow!! perfect ! I used your third suggestion and it worked like a charm. The only thing O need now is to understand how to make the program skip a substitution of '{' if it is one line under 'typedef'. for example when there is                                         typedef struct \n                                                                        { \n                                                                                  }examp;    there has to be no substitution

Comment: @MiSo : That's a big change from your original requirement. Instead of modifying this question, I suggest you open a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is you're looking for the index in @lines. You want this:

```
while (<>) 
{
    my @lines;
    # copy each line from the text file to the string @lines and add a function call after every '{' '
    tie @lines, 'Tie::File', $ARGV or die "Can't read file: $!\n"

    foreach  my $line(@lines) 
    {   
        if   ( index ($lines,'}')== -1 ) # if there is a '}' in the same line don't add the     macro
            {
                $line =~ s/{/'{function(' . $counter++ . ')'/ge;
            }
        print $line;


    }
    untie @lines; # free @lines
}
```

I'm also a bit unclear about how $ARGV is being set. You may want to use $_ in that place based on how you have your script.

Comment: thank you for your response. for some reason if I do it as you suggested it deletes all the content of all the files.

Comment: That's because I forgot to print out if the match is not made. Also I left some extra parens in the if statement. Try it now.

Comment: it has this errors:
Global symbol "@lines" requires explicit package name at filename
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at filename